# how to get a pointer to an array of structure in jna

Tags: java, c, jna

I really want to get a pointer to an array of structures, just like in C, using Java jna. I want to access the `EnumPrinters()` function, and here are the parameters to it:

```
BOOL EnumPrinters(
_In_ DWORD Flags,
_In_ LPTSTR Name,
_In_ DWORD Level,
_Out_ LPBYTE pPrinterEnum,
_In_ DWORD cbBuf,
_Out_ LPDWORD pcbNeeded,
_Out_ LPDWORD pcReturned
);
```

In Java it's

```
public boolean EnumPrinters(int i, String string, int i1, com.sun.jna.Pointer pntr, int i2,
        com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference ibr, com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference ibr1);
```

The problem I am having is that I keep on getting error 122 which means a failure in calling the system call. This is my code:

```
IntByReference  pcbNeeded= new  IntByReference();
int pcb=0;
pcbNeeded.setValue(pcb);
IntByReference  pcReturned= new  IntByReference();
int pcR=0;
pcReturned.setValue(pcR);
PRINTER_INFO_4 printer = new PRINTER_INFO_4();  
PRINTER_INFO_4 PRINT[] = (PRINTER_INFO_4[])printer.toArray(20);
Pointer point = PRINT[0].getPointer();
int size = PRINT[0].size();
Winspool.INSTANCE.EnumPrinters(Winspool.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL,null, 4, point, size,pcbNeeded ,pcReturned);
System.out.println("Operation started!");
System.out.println(printer.pPrinterName);
int rc =  Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
System.out.println("error " + rc);
```

I just want to get all the installed printer on my computer with the code.

Comment: Please, format your code properly. It is difficult to read.

Comment: Isn't rule #1 of java that there are no pointers?

Comment: Are you sure [PrintServiceLookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html) doesn’t meet your needs?  It would make things a lot easier.

Comment: thanks @VGR am going to try that out .. i know it will help .. thanks every buddy

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the first structure instead of a pointer copy of its address, otherwise JNA doesn't know to automatically sync the Java Structure with native memory.

```
public boolean EnumPrinters(int i, String string, 
                            int i1, PRINTER_INFO_4 pntr, 
                            int i2, com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference ibr,
                            com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference ibr1);
```

You should also preserve the original parameter names, it'll make the mapping much more readable.

You could also explicitly call `Structure.write()` on each allocated `Structure` prior to the native call, and `Structure.read()` after the call, but JNA does this automatically when it recognizes a `Structure` in the function signature (including all array elements, if any).